# android get new token from google

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-api, access-token

I have a app in android which works with the google sheets API and write/reads from a spreadheet.

First time I run the app its all good - I get a token from the GoogleAuthUtil **fetchToken** method and I can make API calls (followed this page - http://developer.android.com/google/auth/http-auth.html).

After one hour, the token expires and I need to get a new one, and I read that it should be really easy with the google play services, since it handles the refreshing of the token.

**The problem is - I don't know how to check if the token is valid, and if its not valid, how to get a new one.**

I can't just get a new one, because I don't know if an hour passed since the last time I used the app, and I don't think I should try to get a new token everytime I launch the app.

If someone have any experience working with this, I would appreciate any help.

Been struggling with this for a while. just want to know how to check if token is valid, and if its not valid - how to get a new one!

thanks!

Comment: Did you get the solution to this problem.?